# How to get the red image from gray image in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have an image let say a=imread('example.bmp'i got all three channel from it :

```
R=a(:,:,1);
G=a(:,:,2);
B=a(:,:,3);
```

and i have the gray image of it:

```
 igray=rgb2gray(a);
```

Can I get the red component from the gray image ?

Comment: by definition, all 3 components in a greyscale image have to be equal, otherwise you're not dealing with grey anymore. e.g. greyscale images don't have color components. they're just a single "how bright/dark is this pixel".

Comment: Is your question about separating a gray image into R,G,B channels and using just the R one for something (in which case Marc's comment is pertinent - all three are equal and equivalent to the gray component), or "can I reverse the RGB->grayscale transformation to get the color information back?", in which case the answer is no, because you've thrown color information away. However, there are colorizing algorithms that can give you some fake colors...

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, since igray will be a two dimensional image (a is three dimensional, with the third dimension being colors planes), containing only intensity values for each pixel.

To convert an RGB image to grayscale, rbg2gray uses a formula you can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale)

As you can see, it's a 3 variables equation, therefore you can't find them using intensity value alone.

Answer (score 0):

The `rgb2gray` function effectively does this to every RGB pixel (type `edit rgb2gray`):

```
Gray = 0.298936021293776*Red+0.587043074451121*Green+0.114020904255103*Blue;
```

If you only have `Gray` in the equation above then you have one equation with three unknowns. More information is needed to solve for `Red`.

If you just want an RGB image where every channel has the same components, i.e., those created by `rgb2gray`, then use

```
igray(:,:,3) = rgb2gray(a); % Set last component first to fully allocate array
igray(:,:,1) = igray(:,:,3);
igray(:,:,2) = igray(:,:,3);
```

Or an RGB image where all the channels are equivalent to the red channel:

```
igray(:,:,3) = a(:,:,1);
igray(:,:,1) = a(:,:,1);
igray(:,:,2) = a(:,:,1);
```

The `repmat` function can be used as well if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

While nothing in horchler's very long answer is incorrect, I think you just want to get the red channel from the rgb image which is very easy.

```
A=imread('colorImg.jpg')

redChannel=A(:,:,1)
```

That's it!

That will return a matrix of type uint8, to convert to double, just do double(redChannel) and you can multipy/divide it by 255 as necessary.